# How to get similar kind of sku in catalog search result?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch, sku

I have to create new feature such as did you mean, which is shown in google search engine.

I have multiple similar product sku like G HT2, G HT3 and G HT4. And When I am going to search product with G HT1 (sku). It will show me result as "**no such a result found for 'G HT1'** ". Its true. Because there are no sku like G HT1

But I need there like "**did you mean G HT2, G HT3, G HT4**", when I am going search with G HT1.

I hope you will get my point, what I want to do. 
If any good suggestion, please let me know. It will be great help for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find extension for this task.

Magento Extension : **Did you mean**

Url : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/did-you-mean-8191.html

Thank you, whoever trying to help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please mark your answer as solution.